# How to limit val amount of digits

Tags: javascript

How do i limit the amount of the maximum digits that will be displayed .
For example if i want max 15 digits and after 15 digits  it will show three dots.

```
    '<div class="secondpart"><h4>'+val[0]+'</h3>'+

'</h4><span style="color:#3498db">'+val[1]+'$</span></h4></div></li>';
```

The val i want to limit is val[1] and the maximum digits should be 15 for example.
Thank you for help!

I have tried to add this +val[1].length >= 8+
But it not works because its not the right way i guess

Answer (score 1):

make a little formatter function `formatIt(val[1])`:

```
function formatIt(myVal){
  if(myVal.length > 15)
    myVal = myVal.substring(0,15) + "...";
  return myVal
}
```

if you wanted the 3 little dots and you have a max width in mind (instead of a max number of characters) you could also use css for this:

`text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Answer (score 0):

You can limit you digit through limit of span width:

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: This would probably depend on the font you use.  You've have to ensure it's a fixed width font.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your `val` array contains integers which don't work as expected when trying to determine the number of digits. Try converting the value to a string before testing the length. Here's an example:

```
var val = new Array(1234567890123456, 1234567890123456);

if (val[1].toString().length > 15) {
    val[1] = val[1].toString().substr(0,15) + "...";
}

document.write('<div class="secondpart"><h4>'+val[0]+'</h3>'+
'</h4><span style="color:#3498db">'+val[1]+'$</span></h4></div></li>');
```